# how to break database backup file?

Tags: database, file, upload, break

I created a backup of database, and now i am trying to upload it but it says that database file is too big, and because of that I can't upload it.

So is there a way to break down a  sql, which is database backup file, into pieces or tables, so i can upload them separately.

Or is there any other way to do it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you are using phpMyAdmin to do this, is that correct?

In that case, you have two choices:

1.) Make smaller backups by selecting a few tables at a time

But that can be complicated when it comes to managing indexes, etc.  Abetter option would be to:

2.) Use a database GUI tool such as SQLYog to restore the backup. To do this, you will need to make sure that you have remote access to the database - this will depend on the hosting situation, but even most shared hosts will allow it through RemoteSQL in the cPanel.

To be accurate, will need more details.

Comment: I have backup file, but not tables any more, means that database doesn't exsist any more, it is just database backup.

Comment: Then see option 2 above - can you connect to the new database remotely with something like SQLYog?